# TypeScript isNullOrUndefined

Tags: typescript

How I type such function ?

```
function isNullOrUndefined(obj: any) {
  return typeof obj === "undefined" || obj === null;
}
```

If I return any it means it can be still null or undefined.
I want to use it this way:

```
let a: string | null | undefined = undefined;
if (!isNullOrUndefined(a)) {
    const b: string = a;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Found !

```
function isNullOrUndefined<T>(obj: T | null | undefined): obj is null | undefined {
    return typeof obj === "undefined" || obj === null;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly tried to do here.

Comment: I needed a type guard to convert 'string | null | undefined' into 'string' and use it safely. See strictNullChecks flag : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import { z } from "zod";

const UserSchema = z.object({
  id: z.number(),
  name: z.string(),
});

const UserDataSchema = UserSchema.deepPartial().nullish();

type UserData = z.infer<typeof UserDataSchema>;

const isNullOrUndefined = (data: unknown): data is null | undefined => {
  if (data === null || data === undefined) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const data: UserData = 1
  ? {
      id: 37458,
      name: "cowboy",
    }
  : undefined;

(() => {
  if (isNullOrUndefined(data)) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(data.id);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

to narrow the types if are not null or undefined you can use this function:

```
export function isNullOrUndefined<T>
(value: T | undefined | null): value is (null | undefined) {

 return value === undefined || value === null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [optional - `?:`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/functions.html#optional-parameters) parameter declaration and take the advantage of [loose equality (coercion)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#safely-using-implicit-coercion) between `null` and `undefined` to simplify this function:

```
function isNullOrUndefined<T>(obj?: T | null): boolean {
  // null == undefined so this is true if obj = null or obj = undefined
  return obj == null;
}
```

Comment: The OP's answer is much better as it defines a type guard. Returning a `boolean` isn't as helpful. Also, the optional parameter has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Optional parameter means that you can call isNullOrUndefined() without passing any value, but it doesn’t make sense.